# Difference in passing const &object vs. const object

Tags: c++, constants

Suppose you have a function like this one

```
bool verifyObject(const myObj& obj);
```

or this one

```
bool verifyObject(const myObj obj);
```

As far as I understand, when you pass something like in the second case, a copy is made. However, the compiler might exploit the constness to just pass like in the first case. As such, I see no difference in passing a const object in either way.

Am I wrong?

Comment: http://ideone.com/KW7jAK vs http://ideone.com/yd0B60

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Ok, so the copy constructor is called, but is this always guaranteed? Can't some compilers take advantage of the constness and just skip the call ?

Comment: You are right if the "copy operator" is really no more than a copy.
But if it has some *side effect* it cannot be anymore elided.

Comment: Even if so, at least when the call is not made in the same translation unit, the compiler won't be able to perform this optimization. So you should just always use the `const myObj&` version.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: That's in fact what worried me. If some compilers took that freedom, it would be compiler-dependent behavior. I guess the standard makes extremely clear that the copy constructor must be called.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia ummm... yes it can, even with side-effects.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: But only in situations where elision is allowed. Function arguments are not one of those.

Comment: @MikeSeymour sure it is, when you pass a temporary as parameter.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Sorry, I dashed off my comment without the required level of pedantry. "Function arguments are not necessarily one of those, unless elision is allowed for some other reason".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand, when you pass something like in the second case, a copy is made.

Yes; although in some cases (such as when passing a temporary) the copy could be elided.

> However, the compiler might exploit the constness to just pass like in the first case.

No; unless the argument is a temporary, this is not one of the situations in which a copy can be elided. When calling the function, the compiler may not even know that the parameter is `const` within the function, since a top-level `const` like this can be omitted when declaring the function. So even if it can determine that passing a reference would be equivalent to passing a copy (which won't be the case if the copy-constructor or destructor have observable side effects, or if the class has mutable members), it can't change the calling convention since callers would have no way of knowing about that change.

Having said that, if the function is inline, or your compiler does whole-program optimisation, then optimisations such as this are possible; but only if they don't change the program's behaviour.

Comment: I don't follow - "when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the omitted copy/move"

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: What have temporaries got to do with this? Function arguments aren't temporaries in general.

Comment: But you can pass temps as arguments. `verifyObject(myObj());`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore:  I'm struggling to see the point you're trying to make. You can pass temporaries or non-temporaries as arguments, so a function can't assume that it's a temporary. Are you suggesting that the compiler might generate two versions of the function (one to take temps by ref (or some kind of in-place construction) and another to take non-temps by value) in order to support copy elision? That's possible, but I don't know of any compiler that does it, and anyway the question wasn't about passing temporaries.

Comment: There don't need to be 2 versions of the function. The compiler knows the calling convention and can elide (or not) the copy (construct the temp directly "in" the function). My point is that this is a place where a copy elision is possible.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: OK, I follow you now. But the question wasn't about temporaries, it was about whether the compiler could use the fact the the passed value was `const` to elide the copy when it's not otherwise possible. I've modified the answer to mention that temporaries could have their copies elided, even though it's not particularly relevant.

Comment: It's relevant in the sense that the initial statement was wrong, which can throw people reading this stuff off - if someone doesn't know about this, they could take it for granted ("No this is not one of the situations in which a copy can be elided.") and roll with it until it hits them in the face.

Answer (score 3):

The second one, from the caller's point of view is equivalent to

```
bool verifyObject(myObj obj);
```

Moreover, as declarations, these two are completely equivalent:

```
bool verifyObject(myObj obj);
bool verifyObject(const myObj obj);
```

All top-level consts are ignored in function declarations. The difference manifests only during *a definition*

```
bool verifyObject(const myObj obj)
{
    obj.NonConstMethod(); //compiler error!
}
```

You cannot modify the *copy* inside the function, which the caller doesn't care about at all. It's just for your own purposes, as the function implementer.

Answer (score 1):

With the second example (passing by value) the const modifier makes little difference because the compiler will call the copy constructor of the object and pass a copy of it.
Passing by const reference (const myObj& obj), on the other hand, only passes a reference to the object (does not make a copy).   In that case, the function called cannot change the state of the object through obj.